# Javascript addEventListener : pass argument to external event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In Javascript, when I use `addEventListener`, I would like to call an external method and pass it an event arg:

```
var secondParam= "titi";
element.addEventListener("keydown", handleEventFunc(event, secondParam));
   ...
handleEventFunc: function (eventArg, secondParam) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    var toto = secondParam;
    //do things
}
```

It would be working  equivalent if I were using closure:

```
var secondParam= "titi";
element.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        var toto = secondParam;
        //do things
}
```

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: It's not **you** who is supposed to **call** the function. It's the browser, when the event happens. Hence you have to give the browser a function to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens automagically if you just **reference** the function instead of calling it, as any arguments will be passed by the calling context, in this case the event handler

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", obj.handleEventFunc);

var obj = {
    handleEventFunc: function (event) { // tada, now works
        var key = event.keyCode; // keep the names the same
        //do things
    }
}
```